# Extration of rules placement in SDN

Tags: sdn, mininet, pox, ryu

I am developing an algorithm to solve the rule placement  problem in SDN , and I want to compare my algorithm with already-proposed . In order to do that, I want to conduct a simulation for geting  rules placement as dataset(extract and reuse of rules as dataset than analzying them with an algorithm  ) from tableflow in mininet . However, I am not sure which simulation environment to use . Any help and i  will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi & welcome to StackOverflow ! Please format your issue into something readable :/ The clearer an issue is, the more likely users will help you :-) Also you may want to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get tips on how to format a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [mininet](http://mininet.org/) network emulator to create a topology based on OpenVSwitch. Then you can select from amongst popular SDN controllers such as POX, Ryu, Floodlight, OpenDaylight, ONOS etc.

Some controllers like ONOS have APIs you can use to query the flow-table state at the controller, while in others (like POX), you will have to write your own module.

However, the ovs-ofctl commands of OpenVSwitch, like `dump-flows` can be used to query the flow-table at the switches. You can find the documentation of ovs-ofctl [here](http://www.openvswitch.org/support/dist-docs/ovs-ofctl.8.txt).